# Check Span with JS?

Tags: javascript, html

I have been searching for a while and I haven't found any solution to my problem, so I hope you guys could help me.

I'm creating a method to create user names with your name and last name using input text boxes. When you introduce them, I create the user name and into a `<span>` tag.

The problem is that before to continue, pressing a button, I would like to check if the username has been entered, and I don't know how to do it.

I create this JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function ValidateUser()
    {
        var x = document.getElementById("txtusrname").value;
        if (x == null || x == "") {
            document.getElementById("lblmsg").innerHTML = "Please, first create an username";
            return false;
        }
  else {
            document.getElementById("lblmsg").style.display = "none";
        }
    return true;
    }
</script>
```

And this are the the button and the span with the user name.

```
`<p class="intro" align="center">UserName: <span id="txtusrname"></span></p><div align="center">
<a href="start.html" target="_self"> 
<button type="submit" id="btnenter" onclick="return ValidateUser()">Enter in the App</button></a>
<br>
<label id="lblmsg" style="color:Red;" ></label><br />
</div>`
```

Thank you for the help! And by the way, sorry for my English :D

Comment: Where is your "list" of usernames that you have to determine if the username is already used?

Comment: @LeeTaylor  I think OP means to check if there is any input in `<span>` before continuing

Comment: How will anyone ever insert a user name in a `<span>` element? (Yours has no `contenteditable`...)

Comment: Perhaps you should try to use a textbox instead of a `<span>`. You would not be able to enter a user name into a `<span>`. The validation comes after you can enter data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the value inside `<span>` you have to change
this:

```
var x = document.getElementById("txtusrname").value;
```

to this:

```
var x = document.getElementById("txtusrname").innerHTML;
```

Comment: Thank you all. @stackErr is working perfectly now :D
I tried the textbox but I don't like the final result, but thank I really appreciate the comments.

Answer (score -1):

> I would like to check if the username has been entered, and I don't
>   know how to do it.

How can someone enter anything in `span` ? It is not editable. You should use textbox instead.